# How to use conditional assembly to remove this redundancy using MASM?

Tags: assembly, masm

For the sake of understanding macros and conditional assembly I am using the multiplication operation in the iterative way and I want to remove the redundancy when multiplying any number by zero gives zero without executing the iterative loop. The accumulator represents the value zero (eax = 0) and any other number is labeled by "operand". My code is (not complete),

```
MULTACC macro operand
push ebx                           ;; save ebx and ecx
push ecx

mov ecx,operand                    ;; load ecx with operand
if operand LT 0                    ;; if operand is negative
neg ecx                            ;; make ecx positive for loop
endif

mov ebx,eax                        ;; mov eax to ebx
mov eax,0                          ;; clear accumulator to zero

ifdif <0>,<eax>
if operand NE 1
.while ecx > 0
add eax,ebx                        ;; repetitively add
dec ecx                            ;; decrement ecx
.endw
endif
endif

if operand LT 0                    ;; if operand is negative
mov eax,ebx
neg eax                            ;; negate accumulator, eax
endif
if operand EQ 1
mov eax,ebx
endif

pop ecx                            ;; restore ecx and ebx
pop ebx
endm

LOADACC macro operand
mov eax,operand                    ;; load eax with the operand
endm

main    proc
        
        
        LOADACC 0                             ;eax
        MULTACC 2                             ;operand ecx
        
        CALL OUTACC

        ret
main    endp

OUTACC proc
push eax ; save eax, ecx, and edx
push ecx
push edx
mov temp,eax
INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1fmt, ADDR msg1, temp
pop edx ; restore eax, ecx, and edx
pop ecx
pop eax
ret
OUTACC endp

       end
```

However, supposing that eax = 0 and operand = 2 (or ecx) I don't know why the corresponding listing file generates addresses to non executed loop instructions (seems like "ifdif < 0 >, < eax >" is ignored)? Since we have this condition: "ifdif < 0 >,< eax >" which is false (eax = 0), normally it doesn't proceed to the loop at all! Part of the generated listing file shows,

```
00000000            main    proc
                        
                        
                        LOADACC 0   ;eax
 00000000  B8 00000000       1  mov eax,0 
                        MULTACC 2   ;operand ecx
 00000005  53            1  push ebx 
 00000006  51            1  push ecx
                 1  
 00000007  B9 00000002       1  mov ecx,2 
                 1  if 2 LT 0 
                 1  neg ecx 
                 1  endif
                 1  
 0000000C  8B D8         1  mov ebx,eax     
 0000000E  B8 00000000       1  mov eax,0       
                 1  
                 1  ifdif <0>,<eax>
                 1  if 2 NE 1
 00000013  EB 03       *        jmp    @C0001
 00000015          *@C0002:
                 1  .while ecx > 0
 00000015  03 C3         1  add eax,ebx     
 00000017  49            1  dec ecx         
 00000018          *@C0001:
 00000018  83 F9 00    *        cmp    ecx, 0
 0000001B  77 F8       *        ja  @C0002
                 1  .endw
                 1  endif
                 1  endif
                 1  
                 1  if 2 LT 0 
                 1  mov eax,ebx
                 1  neg eax 
                 1  endif
                 1  if 2 EQ 1
                 1  mov eax,ebx
                 1  endif
                 1  
 0000001D  59            1  pop ecx 
 0000001E  5B            1  pop ebx
```

On the other hand if I opt MULTACC 1 (operand or ecx = 1) I don't see addresses in front of the loop's instructions which means certainly "if operand NE 1" interrupted the loop,

```
 0000000C  8B D8         1  mov ebx,eax     
 0000000E  B8 00000000       1  mov eax,0       
                 1  
                 1  ifdif <0>,<eax>
                 1  if 1 NE 1
                 1  .while ecx > 0
                 1  add eax,ebx     
                 1  dec ecx         
                 1  .endw
                 1  endif
                 1  endif
                 1  
                 1  if 1 LT 0 
                 1  mov eax,ebx
                 1  neg eax 
                 1  endif
                 1  if 1 EQ 1
 00000013  8B C3         1  mov eax,ebx
                 1  endif
                 1  
 00000015  59            1  pop ecx 
 00000016  5B            1  pop ebx
```

That's my question, how to fix the first condition, i.e., "ifdif < 0 >,< eax >", to prevent redundancy (not accessing the loop with eax = 0)  when multiplying zero by any other number?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/if-masm?view=vs-2019) for the `if` MASM conditionals. The expression is evaluated at assembly time.

Answer (score 3):

**MASM [`ifdif <0>, <eax>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ifdif?view=vs-2019) is comparing *those text strings*, not accessing the value stored in EAX at runtime.  "eax" and "0" are of course always different.**  If you want conditional-assembly, you have to use purely assemble-time things like assemble-time constants, not register values.

---

**MASM is an assembler, not a compiler.**  That means it won't do constant-propagation or any other optimizations, only assemble the code you wrote.  Anything else could break some other code that expected to be able to single-step 3 instructions past some point in this, or jump to a specific byte offset.  (Although to be fair, assemblers *do* optimize by picking the shortest encoding, so instruction lengths can change with different assemble-time constants.)

Thus `mov eax,0` can't possibly affect how any other lines assemble.  You need to set some assemble-time constant symbol that you can test with `if`.

Any syntax for testing a register value in any assembler necessarily assembles into a run-time test, including MSVC's `.if` directive ([docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-if?view=vs-2019) "Note that the conditions are evaluated at run time").  Register values aren't available until runtime.  An assembler can't assume that no interrupt or signal handler changes a register value asynchronously.

---

If you want to do the equivalent of `#if 0` or `#ifdef FOO` to disable blocks of code, use assemble-time tests on assemble-time constants, like MSVC's `if` directive, [docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/if-masm?view=vs-2019) "Note that the expressions are evaluated at assembly time."

**If you want to be able to write code that needs optimization to not suck, write it in C** (or any other high-ish level language like Rust that has an optimizing ahead-of-time compiler).  Or LLVM-IR is assembly-like but is actually input to a full optimizing compiler.

Comment: I almost didn't understand your answer, I am trying to solve this problem from a book which requires using "conditional assembly" in this macro and NOT directives!
It states, "Using conditional assembly, modify the MULACC macro defined in this chapter
to not only eliminate the redundant looping but also not generate the loop
instruction itself in the case that the multiplier in the operand is 0 and the answer
is 0, or when it is 1 and the answer is just the value in the accumulator"

Comment: @Hammad: I don't know MASM very well, but clearly anything involving `eax` can't be evaluated at compile time.  I looked up `ifdif`, turns out it's assemble-time *string comparison*, not accessing the value *in* EAX (at runtime).  The point of my answer is that you can rule out the possibility of anything involving EAX being evaluated at compile time, thus `mov eax, 0` can't interact with conditional-assembly.

Comment: @Hammad Based on the quote in your comment, it appears that you're only supposed to use conditional assembly to check if `operand` is 0 or 1. That will work fine as long as you're only passing immediate constants as the operand. It says nothing about checking the value of any registers.

Comment: @Michael Actually it does. That's one part of the problem which I had solved by this condition, "if operand NE 1". In the second part it says, use conditional assembly to avoid the case eax = 0 from generating the loop itself (which is syntactically correct but redundant if eax =0), thus we need conditional assembly like,  "ifdif < 0 >,< eax >" which seems ignored by MASM according to the .lst file to put a condition on the loop. I know that I can't use something like, "if eax NE 0" because the arguments in "if" statements require constants only, not registers, and not memory locations.

Comment: I don't see it. It just says that you should _"not generate the loop instruction itself in the case that the multiplier in the **operand** is 0"_. The part about _"and the answer is 0"_ is just a logical consequence of the operand being 0, since anything multiplied by 0 is 0.

Comment: Also, I would like to mention the book I am reading from is, "(Undergraduate Topics In Computer Science) James T. Streib - Guide To Assembly Language_ A Concise Introduction-Springer (2020) - Shortcut" chapter 7, exercise number 6.

Comment: @Michael if you read this, ""Using conditional assembly, modify the MULACC macro defined in this chapter to not only eliminate the redundant looping..." from the book it has another part before exercises, when he introduced the MULTACC macro, and commented by saying, "...but if the value in eax is 0, then the loop will
iterate redundantly. Can this be solved using conditional assembly? Yes, and this is
left as an exercise for the reader at the end of the chapter."

Comment: Most people here will probably not have this book, and it appears to cost money. You should include all necessary information in your question, since all we have now are fragments.

Comment: @Hammad: I wasn't really trying to solve the specific problem with my answer, just explain the necessary concepts so you'll understand what isn't possible in asm and what is. If you do `mov eax,0` inside the macro, you could also accompany that by setting an assemble-time constant you can `if` later, mabye

Comment: @Michael I think all necessary information are included in the question above if one reads wisely and knows how masm and conditional assembly work. Another aspect, the author demonstrated this type of condition, he implemented the swap macro as an example,
```
swap macro p1:REQ,p2:REQ
ifidni <ebx>,<p2>
xchg p1,ebx
elseifidni <p1>,<ebx>
xchg ebx,p2
else
mov ebx,p1
xchg ebx,p2
mov p1,ebx
endif
endm
```